# Real-time based increment / decrement in C++ console

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-c++

Is there a way to increment / decrement value of a varaible in correspondence to the real-time in a simple C++ console application without using third-party libraries.

For, e.g. in Unity3D game engine, there is something called [Time.DeltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) which gives the time it took to complete last frame. Now, I understand there are no draw update functions or frames in a console app, however what I'm trying to do is able to increment / decrement value of a variable such that, it changes with respect to the time something like,

> variable = 0
>   variable = variable + Time.DeltaTime

so that the variable value increment each second. Is something like this possible in C++ 11 ? so, say if speed is 5 then after 5 seconds the variable has a value 5.

Bascially, I am creating a simple particle system where I want the particles to die after their MAX_AGE is reached. I am not sure how to implement that in a simple C++ console app.

Comment: Have you tried the new [high resolution clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)?

Comment: If you know the current time, and you know how long the particle is supposed to live for, then a simple addition gives you the exact time at which the particle is supposed to die.  Rather than incrementing a counter, simply record that death-time as part of the particle's state, then on each frame, get the current time (using whatever clock API you want to use) and compare it with the particle's death-time.  If the current time is greater than the death-time, get rid of the particle.

Answer (score 0):

For simple timing you can use [std::chrono::system_clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/system_clock/). The [tbb::tick_count](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/timing/tick_count_cls.htm) is a better delta timer, but you said no third party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, delta time is the final time, minus the original time.

```
dt= t-t0
```

This delta time, though, is simply the amount of time that passes while the velocity is changing.

The derivative of a function represents an infinitesimal change in the function with respect to one of its variables. The derivative of a function with respect to the variable is defined as

```
                f(x + h) - f(x)
f'(x) = lim    -----------------
        h->0           h
```

First you get a time, *i.e*  `NewTime = timeGetTime()`.

Then you subtract the old time from a new time you just got. call it delta time , `dt`.

```
OldTime = NewTime;    
dt = (float) (NewTime - OldTime)/1000;
```

Now you sum  `dt` into `totaltime`.

`TotalTime += dt`

So that when `TotalTime`  reaches 5, you end the life of the particles.

```
if(TotalTime >= 5.0f){ 
    //particles to die after their MAX_AGE is reached
    TotalTime=0;

    }
```

...

More interesting reading:

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/

...

example code for Windows:

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")

void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void StepSimulation(float dt);

int main(){

  int NewTime = 0;
  int OldTime = 0;
  int StartTime = 0;
  int TimeToLive = 5000;  ////   TimeToLive 5 seconds
  float dt = 0;
  float TotalTime = 0;
  int FrameCounter = 0;
  int RENDER_FRAME_COUNT = 60;

  // reset TimeToLive
  StartTime = timeGetTime(); 

  while(true){

        NewTime = timeGetTime();    
        dt = (float) (NewTime - OldTime)/1000; //delta time
        OldTime = NewTime;

        // print to screen TimeToLive
        gotoxy(1,1);
        printf("NewTime - StartTime = %d    ", NewTime - StartTime );


        if ( (NewTime - StartTime ) >= TimeToLive){

            // reset TimeToLive
            StartTime = timeGetTime(); 

        }


        // The rest of the timestep and 60fps lock

        if (dt > (0.016f)) dt = (0.016f);  //delta time
        if (dt < 0.001f) dt = 0.001f;

        TotalTime += dt;

        if(TotalTime >= 5.0f){ 
            TotalTime=0;
            StepSimulation(dt);
            }

        if(FrameCounter >= RENDER_FRAME_COUNT){           
            // draw stuff
            //Render(); 
            gotoxy(1,3);
            printf("OldTime      = %d \n",OldTime);
            printf("NewTime      = %d \n",NewTime);
            printf("dt           = %f  \n",dt);
            printf("TotalTime    = %f  \n",TotalTime);
            printf("FrameCounter = %d fps\n",FrameCounter);
            printf("   \n");
            FrameCounter = 0;

        } 
        else{
            gotoxy(22,7);
            printf("%d  ",FrameCounter);
            FrameCounter++;

        }


    }

    return 0;
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}

void StepSimulation(float dt){
    // calculate stuff
   //vVelocity += Ae * dt;

}
```